# MIPS Unknown Instruction Type: 0

Tags: arrays, stack, mips, qtspim

I am writing a program that asks a user for a length of an array from 5 - 12 inclusive.  In the create_array it asks for the length of the array.  It will then jal into 2 more sub programs allocate array first, then read array.

Allocate array takes in 1 argument which is the array base address and then returns the base address allocated.

Read array takes in the array base address and then the array length, and no arguments come OUT.  I am having issues with return arguments after the read array back into main where create_array was originally called.  Create_Array should return OUT the new base address array and the length.

My code then throws the Unknown Instruction Type: 0 at the end of inputting my integers in.  I have a feeling the error is occurring in my create_array after the jal read_array.   I believe i am doing something wrong after that.

Here is my current code:

```
Main:

         .data
    array:      .word 0
    length:     .word 0

###########################################################
        .text
main:
    addi $sp, $sp,  -4  #backup the return address
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    addi $sp, $sp, -8  #zero IN 2 OUT

    jal create_array
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)                      #restore the return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    
    lw $t0, 0($sp)                      #OUT
    lw $t1, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

create_array:

            .data
    dArray:         .word 0
    dLength:        .word 0
    
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter in a number between 5-12: "
    error: .asciiz "Invalid entry! Try Again!\n"
###########################################################
        .text
create_array:
    li $t8, 5
    li $t9, 12
create_array_loop:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt # prompt user
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5   #read the interger
    syscall
    
    blt $v0, $t8, error_line #if less than 5 or greater than 12 branch
    bgt $v0, $t9, error_line
    
    la $t9, dLength #store the length value
    sw $v0, 0($t9)
    
    la $t9, dArray #load array base adddress into t0
    lw $t0, 0($t9)

    addi $sp, $sp -4 #backup ra
    sw $ra 0($sp)
    
    addi $sp, $sp -4    #backup array
    sw $t0, 0($sp)
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -4  #pass 1 IN array, 1 word OUT
    sw $t0, 0($sp)
    
    jal allocate_array  #jump to allocate array
    
    la $t0, dArray
    lw $t0, 0($sp)                  #array base address OUT
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)                  # $ra <- return address (restore)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4                # $sp <- $sp + 4 (1 words)
    
    lw $t0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4                #restore the base address
    
    la $t9, dArray                  #store the base address of the array in t9
    sw $t0, 0($t9)
    
    la $t9, dLength                 #load the length
    lw $t1, 0($t9)
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -4               # $sp <- $sp - 4 (1 word)
    sw $ra, 0($sp)                  # stack <- $ra (backup)

    addi $sp, $sp, -8               # $sp <- $sp - 8 (2 words)
    sw $t0, 0($sp)                  # stack[0] <- base address (backup)
    sw $t1, 4($sp)                  # stack[4] <- array length (backup)
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -8               # $sp <- $sp -8 (2 words: Two IN, Zero OUT)
    sw $t0, 0($sp)                  # stack[0] <- base address (IN)
    sw $t1, 4($sp)                  # stack[4] <- array length (IN)
    
    jal read_array
    
    lw $t0, 0($sp)
    lw $t1, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8                    #restore used registers
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4                    #restore the return address
    
    
    
    jr $ra  #return to calling location
    
    error_line:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, error
        syscall
        
        j create_array_loop

allocate_array:

            .data
###########################################################
        .text

allocate_array:
    

    lw $t0, 0($sp) #array base address
        
    allocate_array_loop:
        li $v0, 9
        sll $a0, $t0, 2
        syscall
        
        sw $v0, 0($sp) #array address OUT
    
        jr $ra  #return to calling location
    
    read_array:
    
                .data
    read_values_prompt_p:       .asciiz "Enter an integer: "
    
    ###########################################################
            .text
    read_array:
        lw $t0, 0($sp)                      #base address
        lw $t1, 4($sp)                      #length
        
    read_array_loop:
        blez $t1, read_array_end
        
        li $v0, 4                           # $v0 <- 4 (setup syscall to print string)
        la $a0, read_values_prompt_p        # $a0 <- base address of "read_values_prompt_p"
        syscall
        
        li $v0, 5                           # $v0 <- 5 (setup syscall to read integer)
        syscall                             # $v0 <- user input
        
        sw $v0, 0($t0)                      # mem[pointer] <- valid input
        
        addi $t0, $t0, 4                    # $t0 <- pointer + 4
        addi $t1, $t1, -1                   # $t1 <- counter + 1
          
        b read_array_loop                   # -> read_values_loop
        
        read_array_end:
        
        jr $ra  #return to calling location
```

Comment: Why are you passing function arguments on the stack instead of just using the `$a` registers? Anyway, the simulator surely told you the exact address at which the error occurred. So start looking there, and work your way backwards until you find where the bug is.

Comment: It doesnt tell me actually, it just gives me the error in the title of the question (Unknown Instruction type: 0).

Comment: In that case, use the breakpoint and single-stepping features until you reach the point where the error occurs, and check the register / stack contents along the way. Note that you have a bunch of duplicate labels, so I'm not sure how you're even able to run the code you've posted.

Comment: Okay i will try that

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out, turns out i was just saving my stacks incorrectly

Comment: Can you provide more detail to help future readers? Or is the solution unlikely to help other people?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).